# mysql left join problem with SUM and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

I have 2 tables in my database: item and category.
Items can be active, or inactive, and have a categoryID that relates to the id of a record in the category table.

i want to perform a query to show all the categories, with the **total cost of active items** for the category

So my goal is to return something looking like this:

```
    +--------+------------+---------------+
    | id     | cat_name   | total_cost    |
    +--------+------------+---------------+
    |      1 | cat 1      | 12            |
    |      2 | cat 2      | 0             |
    |      3 | cat 3      | 45            |
    +--------+------------+---------------+
```

My first query:

```
    SELECT a.*, 
    SUM(b.cost) AS total_cost
    FROM categories a LEFT JOIN items b
    ON(a.id = b.category_id)
    GROUP BY a.category_name
```

works ok, but it returns NULL items instead of 0, and uses all items regardless of active/inactive:

```
    +--------+------------+---------------+
    | id     | cat_name   | total_cost    |
    +--------+------------+---------------+
    |      1 | cat 1      | 44            |
    |      2 | cat 2      | NULL          |
    |      3 | cat 3      | 87            |
    +--------+------------+---------------+
```

my second query adresses the NULL values:

```
    SELECT a.*, 
    SUM(IF(b.cost IS NULL, 0, b.cost)) AS total_cost
    FROM categories a LEFT JOIN items b
    ON(a.id = b.category_id)
    GROUP BY a.category_name
```

and turns out like so:

```
    +--------+------------+---------------+
    | id     | cat_name   | total_cost    |
    +--------+------------+---------------+
    |      1 | cat 1      | 44            |
    |      2 | cat 2      | NULL          |
    |      3 | cat 3      | 87            |
    +--------+------------+---------------+
```

So in my tiny useless brain i try the following query, adding a WHERE clause on table b where active has to = 1 (true)

```
    SELECT a.*, 
    SUM(IF(b.cost IS NULL, 0, b.cost)) AS total_cost
    FROM categories a LEFT JOIN items b
    ON(a.id = b.category_id)
    WHERE b.active = 1 
    GROUP BY a.category_name
```

and i get the following:

```
    +--------+------------+---------------+
    | id     | cat_name   | total_cost    |
    +--------+------------+---------------+
    |      1 | cat 1      | 12            |
    |      3 | cat 3      | 45            |
    +--------+------------+---------------+
```

so as you can se, i would like to return the entire range of categories, even when the right table returns no matching results... Any takes for a million imaginary cool points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT c.id,
          c.cat_name,
          COALESCE(SUM(i.cost), 0) AS total_cost
     FROM CATEGORIES c
LEFT JOIN ITEMS i ON i.category_id = c.category_id
                 AND i.active = 1
 GROUP BY c.id, c.cat_name
```

Comment: it works, no prob. but in mysql you dont need to group by `cat_name`. `id` is suffice. If you want it to be more effective and compliant with SQL standard then use `max(c.cat_name)` or similar group by function in column expressions.

Comment: @Imre L: Using MAX would hide if there were two or more cat_name values associated to the same id, assuming possible.  There's nothing non-standard about defining columns in the group by that don't have aggregate functions on them, and assuming the id value is unique then it's personal choice (though MAX/etc implies that there could be duplicates).

Comment: Bravo good sir - award yourself a big pat on the bag an as many imaginary cool points as you can carry.

I need to do some reading into this coalesce statement to full understand whats going on.

Comment: @Beans: The [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function is an ANSI SQL function that is designed to return the next value (starting from the left) if the current value is NULL.  It's like using [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), but portable to other databases and supports more than two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  SELECT a.*,  
    SUM(Case B.Active When 1 Then b.cost else 0 End) AS total_cost 
    FROM categories a 
       LEFT JOIN items b 
         ON b.category_id = a.id  
    GROUP BY a.category_name
```

or this:

```
    SELECT a.*, SUM(b.cost) AS total_cost 
    FROM categories a 
       LEFT JOIN items b 
         ON b.category_id = a.id 
            And B.Active = 1 
    GROUP BY a.category_name
```

Comment: You are also totally bodacious and earn a gazillion imaginary cool points - thank you. Both of these make a lot of sense, and of course work. Do you have any wisdom on why one method would be 'better' use than another? from a readability perspective i find it easier to understand the first query even though it is more verbose.

Comment: Also, the first one returns null values instead of zero for the total_cost but thats an easy fix. And i think the second one should have b.active = 1, instead of b.cost = 1

Comment: ahh yes, typo... b.active it should be!